# Why is my MIPS assignment not printing what it should>

Tags: mips, mips32

I'm sure I've done the math correct for both factoring and amicability, but it doesn't print past the range and I don't know why. Is my math incorrect? Or am I not actually printing the amicability out?

```
#all the string variables
.data
startrange: .asciiz "Input the start of the range: "            #where the range begins
endrange: .asciiz "What is the end of the range: "          #where the range ends
pairs: .asciiz "The pairs of amicable numbers are: "            #results of amicable #s in range
quit: .asciiz "Unable to check non-positive values\nExiting..."     #circumstance for a < 0 or b < 0
swap: .asciiz "End of range < start of range -- swapping values"    #if the end of range is less than the start of range, swap the values
range: .asciiz "\nRange of numbers: "                   #what the range is (startrange -> endrange)
line: .asciiz "-"                           #dash for range
output1: .asciiz " are amicable numbers"                #results if amicable
output2: .asciiz " are not amicable numbers."               #results if not amicable
a: .word 0                              #input of startrange
be: .word 0                                 #input of endrange

.text
main:
    
    la $a0, startrange  #load address startrange into $a0
    li $v0, 4       #gets ready to print string
    syscall         #prints out startrange
    
    la $s0, a       #loads address of startrange input, a, into $s0
    li $v0, 5       #gets ready to read string
    syscall         #reads startrange input, a
    addi $s0, $v0, 0    
    
    jal negativeInput   #calls for negativeInput fxn to check for negative inputs in a or be
    
    la $a0, endrange    #load address endrange into $a1
    li $v0, 4       #gets ready to print string
    syscall         #prints out endrange
    
    la $s1, be      #loads address of endrange, be, input into $s1
    li $v0, 5       #gets ready to read string
    syscall         #reads endrange input, be
    addi $s1, $v0, 0    
    
    #if(a < 0 || b < 0) then exit
    jal negativeInput   #calls for negativeInput fxn to check for negative inputs in a or be
    
    #if(b < a) swap values
    jal swapping        #jumps to swapping fxn
    
    #print out range of numbers between a and b
    jal printRange      #jumps to printrange method
    
    jal isFactor        #calls for isFactor fxn to check is inputs have factors
    
    jal isAmicable  #calls for isAmicable fxn to check is inputs are amicable
negativeInput:
    slt $t1, $s0, $zero         #if $s0 (a or be) < 0 put in $t1
    bne $t1, $zero, negativeTrue    #if above is true (a !> 0) jumps to negativeTrue fxn
    jr $ra              #return to main
negativeTrue:
    la $a0, quit            #load string quit into $a0
    li $v0, 4           #specifies the print string service
    syscall             #prints out 
    j exit
swapping:
    slt $t1, $s1, $s0       #if $s1 (be) is < $s0 (a) put in $t1
    bne $t1, $zero, swapTrue    #if above is true (a > b) jumps to swaptrue fxn
    jr $ra              #returns to main
swapTrue:
    la $a0, swap            #load string swap into $a0
    li $v0, 4           #gets ready to print
    syscall             #prints out 
    
    move $t2, $s0           #moves input a into $t2
    move $s0, $s1           #moves input be into $s0
    move $s1, $t2           #moves input a into $s1
    
    #addi $t4, $s0, 0       #gets ready to start loop at beginning (a)
printRange:
    la $a0, range           #loads range statement into $a0
    li $v0, 4           #gets ready to print
    syscall             #prints out
    
    li $v0, 1           #ready to print int
    move $a0, $s0           #moving input a into $a0
    syscall             #printing it out
    
    la $a0, line            #moves line statement (-) into $a0
    li $v0, 4           #ready to print string
    syscall             #prints out
    
    li $v0, 1           #ready to print int
    move $a0, $s1           #moves input be into $a0
    syscall             #prints out
exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
isFactor:
    addi $t6, $s0, 0        #i = a to start loop
    addi $t4, $zero, 0      #sum_a = 0
    blt $t6, $s0, isFactorLoop  #while i < a jump to isFactorLoop fxn
isFactor2:
    addi $t6, $s1, 0 #i = be to start loop
    addi $t4, $zero, 0 #sum_be = 0
    blt $t6, $s1, isFactorLoop2 #while i < b jump to isFactorLoop2 fxn
isFactorLoop:
    div $s0, $t6            #a/i
    mfhi $t5            #a/i == $t5
    beq $t5, 0, isFactorLoopTrue    #if a/i == 0 jump to isFactorLoopTrue fxn
isFactorLoop2:
    div $s1, $t6 #be/i
    mfhi $t5 #be/i == $t5
    beq $t5, 0, isFactorLoopTrue2 #if be/i == 0 jump to isFactorLoopTrue fxn
isFactorLoopTrue:
    add $t4, $t6, $t4       #sum_a += i
    move $s3, $t4 #moves sum_a into saved register
    j isFactorLoop          #repeats loop
isFactorLoopTrue2:
    add $t4, $t6, $4 #sum_be += i
    move $s4, $t4 #moves sum_be into saved register
    j isFactorLoop2 #repeats loop
isAmicable:
    addi $t7, $s0, 0        #a/startrange
    addi $t8, $s1, 0        #be/endrange
    addi $t6, $zero, 0      #i=0
    blt $t6, $t8, isAmicableLoop    #if i < be jump
    beq $t6, $t8, isAmicableLoop    #if i == be jump
isAmicableLoop:
    addi $t9, $s1, 0        #j = be
    bgt $t9, $t7, isAmicableIf  #if j > a jump
    beq $t9, $t7, isAmicableIf  #if j == a jump
isAmicableIf:
    #if sum_a == be && sum_be == a they're amicable
    beq $s3, $s1, printIsAmicable #if sum_a == be jump
    beq $s4, $s0, printIsAmicable #if sum_b == a jump
    bne $s3, $s1, printIsNotAmicable #if sum_a != be jump
    bne $s4, $s0, printIsNotAmicable #if sum_be != a jump
printIsAmicable:
    la $a0, output1     #load address startrange into $a0
    li $v0, 4       #gets ready to print string
    syscall
printIsNotAmicable:
    la $a0, output2     #load address startrange into $a0
    li $v0, 4       #gets ready to print string
    syscall
```

I'm sure I did a system call to at least print out the string but thats not working. Even jumped back to main and didn't work. All it prints out to is the range, and doesn't say whether the numbers within that range are amicable.

Comment: Try using the debugger to find exactly where it diverges from expectations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this function:

```
printRange:
    la $a0, range           #loads range statement into $a0
    li $v0, 4           #gets ready to print
    syscall             #prints out
    
    li $v0, 1           #ready to print int
    move $a0, $s0           #moving input a into $a0
    syscall             #printing it out
    
    la $a0, line            #moves line statement (-) into $a0
    li $v0, 4           #ready to print string
    syscall             #prints out
    
    li $v0, 1           #ready to print int
    move $a0, $s1           #moves input be into $a0
    syscall             #prints out
exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

It's important to remember that a label *does not* alter execution flow simply by existing. The program is printing the range and then "falling through" to your `exit` routine. This is because labels are merely a hardware abstraction, a convenience so that you don't have to adjust your "line numbers" (read: memory offsets) of your `jal`, `b`, and `j` statements every time you change your code. The assembler converts your source code, which specifies a label, to either a jump to the memory address where the instruction directly beneath that label is stored, or the distance between the current program counter value and that instruction (measured in bytes), as appropriate. The labels no longer exist in your assembled executable program.

Not only that, your `isFactorLoop` appears to have no way to exit and thus would loop forever.